# Gromov-Hausdorff distance between finite metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, gromov-hausdorff-limit

I am reading "Riemannian Geometry" by Petersen. In his proof for Gromov's precompactness theorem he looks at finite metric spaces with less than $N$ elements and distances between the elements of less than $D$ (let's call the collection of these finite metric spaces $C$). According to the proof these can be viewed as matrices $(d_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, where $d_{ij} = d(x_i, x_j)$, where $x_i, x_j$ are elements of the finite metric space. So these matrices are bounded by $D$, which gives a compact metric space, I guess. So we can find a finite covering for this compact matrix space, which gives a finite covering for the original finite metric spaces.

So this is only possible if the mapping from the collection of finite metric spaces $C$ to the space of compact matrices is continuous, right? In order to see if this mapping is continuous, we would have to assess the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between the finite metric spaces, right? Or is there any other way to see this analogy between the matrices and the finite metric spaces?

Comment: What is the sentence "So this is only possible if the mapping from the collection of finite metric spaces  to the space of compact matrices is continuous" supposed to mean?

Comment: If I understood properly, you can view these finite metric spaces as the described matrices, thus we have some kind of surjective map $f$, that maps the finite metric spaces onto this compact space of matrices. If now we take some finite cover $\bigcup B(M_i, \epsilon)$ of our compact matrix space, we have found our finite cover of the space of the finite metric spaces by $\bigcup f^{-1}(B(M_i, \epsilon))$. My problem is that I don't see how we can write $f^{-1}(B(M_i, \epsilon)) = B(X, \delta)$ for some finite metric space $X$ and $\delta > 0$. Does this make any sense?

Comment: No, it does not. What is a "compact space of matrices"? Also, you **cannot** view a finite metric space (with $n$ elements) as a matrix, only as an element of  $Mat(n)/Sym_n$, where the symmetric group acts on matrices by simultaneous permutation of rows and columns. And I have no idea what the map that is supposed to be continuous. "Some kind of a surjective map" does not cut it.